# firebase function, counter takes too long to update

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have implemented a counter variable in my real time database, the users are able to call the function and upon 4 calls it should run some code.
The problem is that it may take too long to run and update the counter, so if the counter = 1 and two people call the function at a relative same time both of them
will get

```
datasnapshot.child("counter").val() = 1
```

and both of them will set

```
promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').set((counter + 1))) = 2
```

while it should be 3

how can I fix this ? (I guess by either making the update faster or forcing the function to wait for the previous one to end (not sure if possible), or something else that I am missing I am new to firebase & ts)

this is my code:

```
exports.functionTST = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const promises = [];
  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), (key, value) => {
     parse values 
  });

  //set values
  promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/'...).update({
      val1: val2,
    }))

    //counter
    admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey).once('value')
      .then(datasnapshot => {
        let counter = datasnapshot.child("counter").val()
        if (counter === null) {
          promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').set(1))
        } else if (counter < 3) {
          promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').set((counter + 1)))
        } else if (counter == 3) {
          promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').remove())
          //do other stuff
         }
     });

    Promise.all(promises);
    return null
  }
});
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's fix your indentation.

```js
exports.functionTST = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const promises = [];
  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), (key, value) => {
     // parse values 
  });

  // set values
  promises.push(
    admin.database()
      .ref('game/' + matchkey + '/'...)
      .update({
        val1: val2,
      })
  );

  // counter
  admin.database()
    .ref('game/' + matchkey)
    .once('value')
    .then(datasnapshot => {
      let counter = datasnapshot.child("counter").val()
      if (counter === null) {
        promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').set(1))
      } else if (counter < 3) {
        promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').set((counter + 1)))
      } else if (counter == 3) {
        promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').remove())
        // do other stuff
      }
    });

  Promise.all(promises);
  return null
});
```

From this, we can now see a few issues.

The most notable error, is that you aren't awaiting or returning the `Promise` chain properly. When you don't wait for the promises to resolve, your function will get severely [throttled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#do_not_start_background_activities) and network requests (such as updating the database) can be skipped entirely.

```
Promises.all(promises)
return null; // return no data
```

should be

```
await Promises.all(promises) // <-- note addition of await here
return null; // return no data
```

or

```
return Promises.all(promises) // <-- note moving return here
  .then(() => null) // return no data
```

This next block of code does nothing useful. Were you meant to store the result of `JSON.parse` into a new variable? Depending on what you are trying to achieve `Object.entries(data)` might be a better choice.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), (key, value) => {
  // parse values 
});
```

This next block of code spawns a floating `Promise` - you aren't returning it, nor are you storing it into an array like `promises` - so it will cause inconsistent behaviour (like never updating the counter).

```
admin.database()
  .ref('game/' + matchkey)
  .once('value')
  .then(/* ... */)
```

The entirety of the code shown in this block should be replaced by a [transaction operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) instead to streamline the database updates and ensure that it is properly updated.

```
// set values
promises.push(
  admin.database()
    .ref('game/' + matchkey + '/'...)
    .update({
      val1: val2,
    })
);

// counter
admin.database()
  .ref('game/' + matchkey)
  .once('value')
  .then(datasnapshot => {
    let counter = datasnapshot.child("counter").val()
    if (counter === null) {
      promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').set(1))
    } else if (counter < 3) {
      promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').set((counter + 1)))
    } else if (counter == 3) {
      promises.push(admin.database().ref('game/' + matchkey + '/counter').remove())
      //do other stuff
    }
  });

Promises.all(promises)
return null;
```

Adapting the [transaction example](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/7403e77cc6b0c9bae8e9cd9d43f58eb93df2241a/database/read-and-write.js#L108-L124) and merging your other logic gives:

```
//counter
await admin.database() // <-- note addition of await here
  .ref('game/' + matchkey)
  .transaction((matchInfo) => {
    if (matchInfo) {
      // set updated values
      matchInfo[/* The '...' from .ref('game/' + matchkey + '/'...) */].val1 = val2;
      // e.g.
      // matchInfo.round1.val1 = val2;
      // OR
      // matchInfo.round1 = Object.assign(
      //   matchInfo.round1 || {}, // <-- creates the property when it is missing
      //   {
      //     val1: val2
      //   }
      // );

      // handle & update counter
      const counter = matchInfo.counter || 0;
      if (counter < 3) {
        matchInfo.counter = counter + 1;
      } else {
        // clear counter and do other stuff
        delete matchInfo.counter;
        // e.g.
        // matchInfo.winner = matchInfo.players[0]
      }
    }
    return matchInfo; // apply changes
  });

return null; // return no data to the caller
```

After implementing the above block, your function can become something similar to:

```
exports.functionTST = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // parse request body
  const matchkey = data.matchkey;
  /* ... */

  // update match information
  await admin.database() // <-- note addition of await here
    .ref('game/' + matchkey)
    .transaction((matchInfo) => {
      /* ... */
    })
  
  return null;
```

To ensure that the function returns appropriate errors, you should surround each part in try-catch blocks and throw an appropriate [`HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.functions.HttpsError) so failures can be handled gracefully by the caller on the client side:

```
exports.functionTST = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // parse request body
  try {
    const matchkey = data.matchkey;
    /* ... */
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Unexpected error while handling request data: ', err);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Could not parse request data');
  }

  // update match information
  try {
    await admin.database() // <-- note addition of await here
      .ref('game/' + matchkey)
      .transaction((matchInfo) => {
        /* ... */
      })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Unexpected error while updating match information: ', err);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Could not update match information');
  }
  
  return null; // return no data to the caller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First run after deploy take time because the [cold start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM&t=7s) happening, And consider using transaction to prevent race condition.